# how to get captcha numbers separately using python

Tags: python, captcha, text-recognition

I have this specific 3-digit of captcha, like:

[image]

I am trying to slice the 3 digits, I tried to use **pytesseract** module to recognize text
in images but it's not so accurate. so I researched about it and fount out that I could make the background completely white so that I could crop all the extra space from the picture and dividing the picture to 3 pieces would most likely happens to be what I need, so I'm looking for a way to implement this filter and crop it and slicing it into three pieces

I found out **PIL** module can help me import the image on python

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("captcha.jpg")
```

and I'm looking for a way which I can make the background totally white and crop the extra spaces and divide the picture into three pieces, thanks for your guidance in advance.

Comment: @Tim Captcha are designed for 2 purposes:block robots and track people even if they don't want to be tracked. Is it ethical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I have found this library called **cv2** with this method called **threshold**

For every pixel, the same threshold value is applied. If the pixel value is smaller than the threshold, it is set to 0, otherwise it is set to a maximum value.

```
img = cv.imread('gradient.png',0)
ret,thresh1 = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
```

in the example above it takes an image and if the pixel is below 127 it makes it completely white, otherwise it's going to be completely black.

further reading:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html